# Is it possible to save a variable in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I would like to save a variable in the controller to be able to use it for all methods so I declared 3 private strings

```
public class BankAccountController : Controller
{
     private string dateF, dateT, accID;
    //controller methods
}
```

Now this method changes their values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(string dateFrom, string dateTo, string accountid)
{
     dateF = dateFrom;
     dateT = dateTo;
     accID = accountid;
     //rest of the code
}
```

I used a breakpoint and the variables are being changed when I call that controller method, however when I call other controller methods such as these below the private strings are being reset to emtpy strings, how can I prevent it from happening?

```
public ActionResult Print()
        {
            return new ActionAsPdf(
                "PrintFilter", new { dateFrom = dateF, dateTo = dateT, accountid = accID }) { FileName = "Account Transactions.pdf" };
        }

    public ActionResult PrintFilter(string dateFrom, string dateTo, string accountid)
    {
            CommonLayer.Account acc = BusinessLayer.AccountManager.Instance.getAccount(Convert.ToInt16(accID));
            ViewBag.Account = BusinessLayer.AccountManager.Instance.getAccount(Convert.ToInt16(accountid));
            ViewBag.SelectedAccount = Convert.ToInt16(accountid);
            List<CommonLayer.Transaction> trans = BusinessLayer.AccountManager.Instance.filter(Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom), Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo), Convert.ToInt16(accountid));
            ViewBag.Transactions = trans;
            return View(BusinessLayer.AccountManager.Instance.getAccount(Convert.ToInt16(accountid)));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Every request you make a new instance of the controller will be created, therefore you're data is not shared between requests. There's a few things you can do to save the data:

```
Session["dateF"] = new DateTime(); // save it in the session, (tied to user)
HttpContext.Application["dateF"] = new DateTime(); // save it in application (shared by all users)
```

You can retrieve the values in the same way. Of course, you could also save it somewhere else, bottom point is, controller-instances are not shared, you need to save it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The following method is very simple, and makes sure the variable is tied to the current user, instead of that it is used in your entire application. All you need to do is type the following code in the controller:

```
Session["dateF"] = dateFrom;
Session["dateT"] = dateTo;
Session["accID"] = accountid;
```

and whenever you want to use that variable, for instance you want to give it as an parameter to a method, you just type this:

```
MyMethod(Session["dateF"].ToString());
```

That is how you save and use a variable in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static field in the controller so it's shared between all requests.

`private static List<someObject> yourObjectList;`

Comment: Clear solution :)